# Pass a generic class type as a parameter of a generic function

Tags: angular, typescript, generics

I'm using a converter (external library) that has a method **fromJson** like the one below.
I want to build a generic RESTService, but i don't know how to pass the generic class type to the method.

```
// From the library
export declare type Clazz<T> = {
  new (...args: any[]): T;
};

// From the library
export class Converter {
  ...
  public fromJson<T>(json: any, clazz: Clazz<T>): T { ... }
  ...
}

// ******************************************************

// My Service on my Angular app
class RESTService<T> {
  ...
  public save(t: T): Observable<T> {
    return this.httpClient.post('http://...', t)
      .pipe(map(res => this.converter.fromJson(res, ???)));
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're passing an object to `fromJson`? Seems like you just want to say that `fromJson` returns an object of type `Clazz<T>`... So `fromJson(json: any): Class<T> {}`.

Comment: fromJson is a method of an external library, i can't change that.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir I have updated the question.

Comment: Looks like it's asking for a constructor function or class type.

Comment: Yes, but how can i pass another generic class type T of my generic rest service?

Comment: Please show how `RESTService<T>` is being instantiated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `t.constructor` as the `Clazz<T>` argument. You'll need to tell TypeScript it is of the right type using `as`:

```js
// From the library
declare type Clazz <T> = {
    new(...args: any[]): T;
};

// From the library
class Converter {
    public fromJson<T>(json: any, clazz: Clazz<T>) { return new clazz(); }
}

class Test {
    public testIt<T>(test: T) {
        const converter = new Converter();
        var o = converter.fromJson("{}", test.constructor as new (...args: any[]) => T);
        return o;
    }
}

class TestObj {
    testProp: string = "hello";
}

var o = new TestObj();
var t = new Test();
var a = t.testIt(o);
console.log(JSON.stringify(a));
```

[This seems to compile and work in the TypeScript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=%2F%2F%20From%20the%20library%0D%0Adeclare%20type%20Clazz%20%3CT%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20new%28...args%3A%20any%5B%5D%29%3A%20T%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20From%20the%20library%0D%0Aclass%20Converter%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20fromJson%3CT%3E%28json%3A%20any%2C%20clazz%3A%20Clazz%3CT%3E%29%20%7B%20return%20new%20clazz%28%29%3B%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Test%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20testIt%3CT%3E%28test%3A%20T%29%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20converter%20%3D%20new%20Converter%28%29%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20o%20%3D%20converter.fromJson%28%22%7B%7D%22%2C%20test.constructor%20as%20new%20%28...args%3A%20any%5B%5D%29%20%3D%3E%20T%29%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20o%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20TestObj%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20testProp%3A%20string%20%3D%20%22hello%22%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20o%20%3D%20new%20TestObj%28%29%3B%0D%0Avar%20t%20%3D%20new%20Test%28%29%3B%0D%0Avar%20a%20%3D%20t.testIt%28o%29%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log%28JSON.stringify%28a%29%29%3B), but as always, you should test it out in your own environment.

I did alter `fromJson` just so that I could get a loggable result, and obviously `testIt` is not exactly the same as your (Angular?) function, but hopefully it gets you going in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

1. The library you are using is very bad and has semantic errors. `new` is a keyword used to initialize an instance of a class type. The return type is should always be consistent with this class type. The correct definition should be:

   ```js
   export declare type Clazz<T> = {
     new (...args: any[]): Clazz<T>;
   };
   ```
2. Solve this problem. You can always use the keyword `as` and `Object.create(null)` to convert most object types to avoid compiler checking:

   ```js
   class RESTService<T> {
     ...
     public save(t: T): Observable<T> {
       let clazz = Object.create(null) as Clazz<T>;
       // clazz.someValue = 'Hello world';
       return this.httpClient.post('http://...', t)
         .pipe(map(res => this.converter.fromJson(res, clazz)));
     }
     ...
   }
   ```

   `Object.create(null)` give you a js object without any method binding --- a pure struct space.